# realtime sync files between ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, storage, rsync, synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [M-M or M-S replication of EBS volume across multiple EC2 instances](https://serverfault.com/questions/266122/m-m-or-m-s-replication-of-ebs-volume-across-multiple-ec2-instances)
>   [realtime sync of files between instances](https://serverfault.com/questions/435173/realtime-sync-of-files-between-instances)

In my implementation, I have a java app that reads/writes files into local storage. Since the same java app will be running across multiple instances in AWS, i need to sync these files (created/updated by the java app) across all instances in realtime. Is this possible, if not, any alternative to achieve the goal?